# Simple Ubuntu scripts to connect to a server via terminal

Tags: ubuntu, terminal

Im relatively new to Ubuntu, Im wondering how easy it is to write what I think is called a shell script to make tasks a little easier.

For example I frequently connect to a server - ssh -p 123 me@mysite.com

Can and how could I shorten this to a shorter command like "mysite" or "ssh mysite"

Thanks.

Comment: [Books for learning shell scripting](http://serverfault.com/questions/92180/best-book-for-learning-linux-shell-scripting)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Alias is a quick and easy way, but a more secure one is to set up an ssh profile. In your ~/.ssh/config, put

```
Host mysite
Port 123
Hostname mysite.com
User me
```

Then you connect by just typing

```
ssh mysite
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe an alias in your shell is sufficient : `alias mysite='ssh -p 123 me@mysite.com'`
Put that in your .bashrc (if your shell is the bash) and reload it by `source .bashrc`

Answer (score 0):

For this particular case, you can add the following to the ssh config file (in ~/.ssh/config):

```
Host mysite.com
User me
Port 123

Host mysite2.com
User otherme
Port 2222
```

This will shorten the command to `ssh mysite.com`, which is not bad, and will also work with other programs relying on ssh (scp, sftp, many version control systems, etc)

You could go further and add a shorter hostname in /etc/hosts:

```
123.456.1.1   mysite   mysite.com
```

then replace `mysite.com` by `mysite` in the other places.